# AndroidStudio separate module code not accessible

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have added a separate module to my Android Studio project and for some reason even though the module shoes up in my project I am not able to import or access the classes of that module

[image]

My app build.gradle contains `compile project(':shared')`

and my settings.gradle for the project contains

```
include ':shared'
project(':shared').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../shared')
```

The code is visible on the left hand pane under the shared folder but I am not able to access those classes from my Android Classes

Comment: You need to compile the module in settings.gradle and build.gradle

Comment: did you add `compile project(':shared')` to the `app` module's `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Or let it add the dependencies on the shared module like the popup says

Comment: @Karakuri yes and I updated my post to show that

Comment: @cricket_007 clicking add the dependency doesn't actually do anything so I am not sure whats going on there however I do have the dependency in the build.gradle already

Comment: @user2844358 It looks like  you are using two github repos as two modules ??Is it?? Please post your both manifest file and all build.gradle file complete code ??it will be easier to look what & where the issue lies??Also logcat...

Comment: In which `settings.gradle` did you add those lines? I see more than one `settings.gradle`, those lines need to be in the root `settings.gradle`. (It's easier for me to see which gradle file belongs where by changing to the "Project" view in the files navigator pane.)